# ag-grid-vue: how to detect row click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue, onrowclick

I am following the example [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/vuejs-grid).

All works and now I want to detect a row click and get the event's data.

Here is my `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <ag-grid-vue style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"
           class="ag-theme-alpine"
           :columnDefs="columnDefs"
           :rowData="rowData"
           :rowClicked="onRowClicked"
  >
  </ag-grid-vue>
</template>

<script>
import {AgGridVue} from "ag-grid-vue";

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      columnDefs: null,
      rowData: null
    }
  },
  components: {
    AgGridVue
  },
  methods:{
    onRowClicked(params) {
      console.log(params);
      console.log(params.node.data);
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.columnDefs = [
      {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make', sortable: true, filter: true },
      {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model', sortable: true, filter: true },
      {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price', sortable: true, filter: true }
    ];

    fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/grid-packages/ag-grid-docs/src/sample-data/smallRowData.json')
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(rowData => this.rowData = rowData);
  }
}
</script>

<style>
@import "../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
</style>
```

However, the method `onRowClicked` is not called when I click on a row.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
:rowClicked="onRowClicked"
```

with

```
@rowClicked="onRowClicked"
```

To make the `ag-grid-vue` component emit the event when a row is selected.

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64387203/ag-grid-vue-how-to-detect-row-click]